# regex to match any string whether Unicode or not?

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I want to match any string between title tags

```
$string = "<title>نص عربى English text</title>";

$pattern = '/<title>(regex.here)<\/title>/u';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
print_r($matches);
} else {
echo 'No matches.';
}
```

the return should be

```
نص عربى English text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your PCRE is compiled with [unicode support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php), you can just match against the letter space from the unicode standard.

```
 <?php
 preg_match_all('|<title>(\p{L}+)</title>|u', $string, ...);
```

Please note the *u*-modifier, that enables unicode matching.

Comment: It works fine after normalize the encoding before I apply the regex thanks to @fsb

Answer (score 2):

try with

```
$string = "<title>نص عربى English text</title>";

$pattern = '/<title>([\x{0000}-\xFFFF]*.*?)<\/title>/u';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
print_r($matches);
} else {
echo 'No matches.';
}
```

Comment: not working for arabic text or "Unicode text" witch not UTF-8 encoded with . (dot)!!

Comment: Better yet, use `*?` as quantifier, just to be safe from input that has multiple closing title tags. Or use `[^<]*` inside the capture which should be faster.

Comment: still not, it works fine if the string is UTF-8 encoding only and the title will be in any encoding like windows-1256 or whatever !

Answer (score 1):

Copy pasted into a file,  changed the match expression to get anything between title tags and print the first match:

```
<?PHP
$string = "<title>ﻦﺻ ﻉﺮﺑﻯ English text</title>";
$pattern = '/<title>(.*)<\/title>/u';
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    print($matches[0][1]."\n");                                                      
} else {
    echo 'No matches.';
} 
?>
```

output:

```
rasjani@laptop:~$ php unitest.php 
نص عربى English text
rasjani@laptop:~$
```

Comment: it works well for me if the title was in page with UTF8 ENCODED ONLY !! but if the page was encoded in windows-1256 doesn't work

Comment: @D3VELOPER: correct. To do what you want with PCRE you need to normalize the encoding before you apply the regex. You can use iconv to convert from  windows-1256 to UTF-8.

Comment: @rasjani: the `(.*)` is a bit aggressive. At least put a `?` in there: `(.*?)`.

Answer (score 0):

The (??????) will only match something which is exactly 6 characters long, and it will only match '?'.  To match 'any' character, use '.' and to match repeating number of them use '.*'

Matching HTML tags like that is not easy in regex, so you should probably use a HTML parser for that instead.

As an aproximation you could do something like

     `/<title>([^<]*)<\/title>/`

Which will almost work, as long as your text does not contain a '<'

Comment: Pretty sure he put `(??????)` to denote the part of the regex he wasn't sure about...